# If $\lim_{x\to x_0+}\frac{df}{dx}=K$ exists then $f$ has right derivative and is equal to $K$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be continuous at $[x_0;x_0+h]$ and have finite derivative at $(x_0;x_0+h)$.

If the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\frac{df}{dx}=K
$$
exists then $f$ has right derivative and is equal to $K$ ($K$ can be finite or infinite).

> Can you help how from this we get that derivative of $f$ is continuous or has only *second* order discontinuous
> points?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah We proved this using MVT but can't see why it can't have first order discontinuous  points.

Answer (score 1):

If $K$ finite, for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a constant $\delta>0$ such that
$$|f'(x)-K|<\epsilon$$
for all $x_0<x<x_0 +\delta$
Thus for all $x,y \in (x_0,x_0+\delta)$
$$\left| \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} -K\right|<\epsilon$$
By continuity of $f$, this implies
$$\left| \frac{f(x_0)-f(y)}{x_0-y} -K\right|<\epsilon$$
for all $y \in (x_0,x_0+\delta)$
Hence forth the conclusion.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question but I can't see from your answer  how we can show that derivative of $f$ can't have first order discontinuous points.

Comment: So what you proved is that if $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_1^+}f'(x)$ exists, it must be equal to $f'(x_1)$ , same goes for the left derivative. So if one-sided limit of $f'$exists for both side, they must equal. Hence there is no jump discontinuity.